# How does xcorr normalize cross-correlation data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, normalization, cross-correlation

I found some documentation on how `xcorr` computes the normalized cross correlation in MATLAB:

[image: http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/toolbox/signal/spectra3.html]

However, I can't find any information on how `xcorr` computes the normalization in Matplotlib. What is the normalization formula it uses? Is it the same as the `xcorr` function in MATLAB?

**References**

http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/toolbox/signal/spectra3.html

Comment: The great thing about open source software such as matplotlib is that it is open.. you can just check [the source](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/_modules/matplotlib/axes/_axes.html#Axes.xcorr) yourself and you'll find that `correls /= np.sqrt(np.dot(x, x) * np.dot(y, y))`.

Comment: The OP does have a point that this should be included in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xcorr.html) though.

Comment: Matplotlib `xcorr` defaults to `normed=True` which normalizes only the magnitude, but not the mean. To normalize data to mean=0, you can add the argument `detrend=mlab.detrend_mean`.